# Do not want to repeatedly generate objects when calling the API

Tags: spring, api, object

In Spring, There's an object that I need to create it when I call this API, but the parameters of this object are different every time.
Isn't this a good idea? How can I improve it? Reset parameters with setter？

Comment: You're not really using the same object each time if its parameters are different. Why do you think instantiating an object on each request is a bad thing? (Sharing and mutating one between requests is likely to be a very bad idea, what if 2 requests come in at once).

A code sample would help demonstrate exactly what you are doing

Comment: But if there are more requests, many objects will be generated, which is a bad thing.

Comment: Why is that a bad thing? Are these objects *HUGE*? What are they?

Comment: that's a List Object, I think that's huge.

Comment: Not on it's own. A list of what size, containing what. Also, I'm pretty sure at this point that this is premature optimisation. If you haven't run a profiler and determined there is a problem you shouldn't be trying to find a solution (to a problem that probably doesn't exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I believe you may be at risk of premature optimization, that is where you spend large amounts of time worrying about something which doesn't matter. Worse still, optimizing for memory or cpu generally reduces readability which can make bugs far easier to introduce. So optimizing for memory or cpu is something you should only do if you have a demonstrable problem and a profiler has shown that this area is the root of the problem (a memory or CPU profiler as appropriate)

Take your example, you are concerned that each request generates a List (presumably an Arraylist?). These are small data structures in their own right (likely a tiny percentage of your total memory usage), they only get big when they contain large numbers of other large objects, worse you are suggesting resetting a list and reusing it between api requests. This reuse and resetting of the list would introduce a subtle bug that would only occur intermittently (the worst kind of bug); if two API request overlap (highly likely for a web server) then they will both use the list at the same time; state from request A may leak into B or vice versa. It is almost a perfect example of why you shouldn't prematurely optimize.

(If the list contained static data that never changed then my answer might be different)